# Hibernate - Formula - invalid Query

Tags: java, hibernate, formula

I have a question about Hibernate Formula.

Let us assume that I have an entity "garage" in which there are numerous "cars". Now I would like to add a property in the car class that tells me which number of car it is in the garage.

I created this formula on the car-class:

```
@Formula("(SELECT pos FROM (SELECT rownum AS pos, c.id FROM garage g "
+ "LEFT JOIN car c ON g.id = c.garage_id "
+ "WHERE g.id = GARAGE_ID "
+ "ORDER BY c.date) WHERE id = CAR_ID)")
```

The entity car has both properties (ID and GARAGE_ID). How can I now incorporate these into the Formula?

Furthermore I have the problem that Hibernate always generates an invalid SQL from it.

Pos becomes query0_.pos. However, this is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

The rule with the SQL fragment inside the `@Formula` annotation is that any "bare" (unqualified) column reference is going to be qualified by the alias of the entity the formula belongs to.

So, for example, in this `@Formula`:

```java
@Formula("(select upper(isbn) || ' ' || upper(a.name) from authors a where a.id=author_id)")
```

The columns which are going to get a qualifier attached to them are `isbn` and `author_id`.

So in your example:

- you should add a qualifier to `pos` to suppress this behavior, but
- you should leave `id` and `garage_id` unqualified since they belong to the car entity.

However, there's something that seems rather confusing in your code. Why would you be joining back to the `car` table here? That doesn't look quite right.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.

The situation described above is only for example. I need the position in the garage in the car class. You may have a nicer idea - or a simple SQL statement :)